# Подгрузка данных из другого файла

Tags: php, html

Есть много значений, из которых складывается таблица со значениями. Т.к. значений много, и хранятся они в мускуле, доставать их из мускула (а это 80~ селектов) - долго, не оптимизировано, и вообще на прямую в странице .php это происходит долго, страница грузится 10~ секунд.Решил сделать подгрузку раз в 2 дня.Запись значений в файлик уже сделал, генерится  с значениями из мускула.

Как эту таблицу подгрузить в страницу, дабы выглядело корректно?

Пробовал iframe, но там это выглядит как паст для кода на ucoz'овских форумах.
Пробовал и всю страницу генерить новую, да в переменную генератора не лезет.
Javascript не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще всего сделать функцию, которая возвращает сгенерированный html. Внутри функции сделать условие, если прошло меньше 2-х дней, соответственно берёте (возвращаете) данные из файла, иначе генерируете новое содержимое файла, записываете его в файл и его же возвращаете. 
для записи в файл используйте

```
file_put_contents($path, $data);
```

для чтения

```
 $data = file_get_contents($path);
```

Если бы Вы написали ваш код, можно это бы было и показать на вашем коде....

Comment: Говорю ж, с генерацией разобрались, с обновлением в срок разберется другой человек, нужно просто вывести эту таблицу, include(); не помогает, говорит мол - файла нет такого

Comment: добавил в ответ функции. Если $path и там, и там одинаков, то проблем не должно быть...на всякий случай проверьте, создается ли файл.

Comment: файл то не должен создаваться, он уже есть, спасибо, сработало